# AWS Glue Crawler - Scheduling crawler run two times a day

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue Crawler. I want to run this crawler two times a day . I have few questions on same:

1. The time we configure to run. Will be in UTC or the time will be depending on which region we are. Example for "us-east-1" time will be in EST ?
2. I want to run Crawler two times a day (8 AM CST & 8 PM CST), so if I convert this to UTC it will be -> 2 PM & 2 AM in UTC.
3. What cron expression I can write to run two times a day at 2 AM and 2 PM UTC ?

I understand if it has to run one time a day at particular time, we have to do as below :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It will run always in UTC.
2. `cron(0 2,14 * * ? * )`